# CCライセンスの資料を入れたプログラムのライセンス

Tags: ライセンス

wikipediaの記事を元に作られた資料はクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスになりますが、
クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスで作成された資料をプログラムに入れて使用する場合、
そのプログラムはクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスとして頒布しなければならないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

＃「資料をプログラムに入れて使用する場合」の意味は、「資料データをプログラムソースに埋め込んで使用する場合」と解釈して回答します。

ライセンスの条件のうち「継承」(ShareAlike)を指定している資料であれば、埋め込んだプログラムも元資料のライセンス(CC-BY-SA, CC-BY-NC-SA)にする必要があると解釈するのが妥当と考えます。

[CC-BY-SAの説明(日本語サイト)](https://creativecommons.jp/licenses/#licenses)

> 原作者のクレジット（氏名、作品タイトルなど）を表示し、改変した場合には元の作品と同じCCライセンス（このライセンス）で公開することを主な条件に、営利目的での二次利用も許可されるCCライセンス。

＃NCが加わると商用利用不可になる。

「継承」を指定していないCCライセンスの資料であれば、プログラムをCCライセンスにする必要はないかと思います。

---

なお、その「資料」をプログラムに埋め込まずに、独立したファイルにして、プログラムから読み込むようにすれば、CC-BY-SA, CC-BY-NC-SAライセンスの場合でも「継承」の影響は受けないかと思います。
(プログラムは二次創作物にならないため)
そのようにプログラムしたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: プログラムに資料データをリテラル文字列で埋め込む。→元資料のライセンスにする必要がある。XML、CSV等のファイルにしてプログラムから読み込むようにする。→元資料のライセンスの影響を受けない。という理解でよろしいでしょうか。プログラムは二次創作物にならないという件は知りませんでした。てっきり二次創作物になると思っていたのですが違ったのですね。

Comment: 蛇足かも知れませんが、CCライセンスのものに限らず、元の著作物を改変して作られたプログラムは二次創作物です。元の著作物を改変せず読み込むだけなら、そうならないでしょう、という意図で回答書いてます。

Answer (score 1):

https://creativecommons.jp/faq/#a5

クリエイティブ・コモンズの、日本語のサイトを発見したので、ここに記します。

> ソフトウェアにCCライセンスを付けることはできますか？
>
> 可能ですが、お勧めはできません。
> CCライセンスは、ソースコードとオブジェクトコードについては、適用の対象として考慮していないからです。Free Software Foundationによって公開されているライセンス（日本語参考訳）や、Open Source Initiativeがリストに挙げているライセンス（日本語参考訳）等、ソフトウェアに適したライセンスが既に他にありますので、そちらのご利用をご検討ください。これらのライセンスは、CCライセンスと異なり、ソフトウェア専用のライセンスとして設計されています。
> クリエイティブ・コモンズは法律に関する専門的な知識がなくても簡単に理解することができるコモンズ証（例：CC-BY）と、コンピュータが読み取るメタデータを使って、いくつかのフリー・ソフトウェアやオープン・ソフトウェアのライセンスを取り込んでいます。
> 例としては、CC-GNU GPL（コモンズ証）、CC-GNU LGPL（コモンズ証）、 CC-BSD（コモンズ証）などです。これらのライセンスを使えば、既に完成されているこれらのソフトウェア・ライセンスを使いつつ、CCライセンスと同じように、人が理解しやすいライセンスの解説（コモンズ証）とコンピュータが読み取るメタデータを表示することができます。
> ただし、注意していただきたいのは、クリエイティブ・コモンズは、これらのソフトウェア・ライセンスの代替ライセンスを提供しているわけではありません。単に、元の許諾書と共に人とコンピュータのどちらもが読める説明のあるライセンスを合わせただけです。

ご質問では、しなければならないのでしょうか？とあるように、する必要はないとか、してはいけないとか、してもよいという話になるかと思いましたが、曖昧な事が書かれていますね。詳しい事はリンク先を辿っていただければと思います。